# Foundation grid overview block sizes equality

Tags: image, grid, zurb-foundation

I'm working on a page where a lot of images are being presented in a grid. I am using the Foundation grid for this. I have three types of sizes: landscape, portrait and square. In the design, the landscape and portrait blocks are exactly the same size(just turned 90deg). And that's where the problem begins..

I rather not use pixels to setup the dimensions of my images here, so is there a clean way I can make the sizes of 'landscape' and 'portrait' the same without using pixels?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="products">
    <div class="product landscape medium-12 large-8 xlarge-6  columns overview">
        <img src="img/mes_liggend.jpg">
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <p>Subtitle is longer</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product portrait medium-12 large-8 xlarge-6 columns overview">
        <img src="img/mes_staand2.jpg">
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <p>Subtitle is longer</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product square medium-12 large-8  xlarge-6 columns overview">
        <img src="img/gude5.jpg">
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <p>Subtitle is longer</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done without some reference size.  You can try some CSS like this:

```
.products img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100rem;
}
```

But your portrait images will narrow up (look squashed).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have found my solution in: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/.